# Determine if the graph $f(x) = \ln(x)$ has any critical numbers

Tags: integration, derivatives, logarithms, transcendental-equations

Determine if the graph $f(x) = \ln(x)$ has any critical numbers. The derivative would be 
$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Can you define what a *critical number* is for me?

Comment: What do you mean here? Are you asking if the function $f$ has any critical points?

Comment: Yes I do mean critical points, sorry my teacher uses both critical numbers and critical points interchangeably but yes critical points as in when the derivative is set equal to zero

Comment: So, critical points are points where the derivative does not exist or where it has value zero. You've noted the derivative always exists. Is $f'(x)$ ever zero? Note a function need not have any critical points.